# Correct RESTful method for checking input data matches database record

Tags: rest

I have an application that takes user's input personal details (name, dob, etc.) and looks for a match in the database. I am not creating a record, nor editing one.

Now normally I'd use GET, but GET doesn't allow me a body, and all the data that needs to be checked has to be sent up. I run a database query against all the user's inputs to find a match. If the database returns a match then one is found, otherwise it returns an empty array and no match is found.

So can you recommend the correct RESTful method (HTTP) that I might use for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the semantics of the payload of a `POST` operation are defined by the service itself, it should be used in any case where the other operations do not fit. `POST` is therefore not only used to create new resources but also to trigger certain calculations and stuff like that.

The general question however is, why do you need such a method? If you fear overwriting any changes done by an other client to the resource between you fetching the state of a resource and requesting an update, i.e., you should consider using conditional requests as defined in [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) where either an `ETag` hash is calculated for the current state or the `Last-Modified` value is taken and added to response header. A client could then send the request including the payload to check first including a `If-Match` or `If-Unmodified-Since` header requesting the server to apply an update only if the precondition holds. If it fails the server would tell you that with a `412 Precondition Failed` error response.

Comment: This answer is correct, however you misunderstand my use case, so I'll clarify for completeness. I am using this method to register users who I cannot guarantee will have an email address. The details provided are used to match users against a predefined record. Thanks for your advice about POST, this is what I will use.